# tkinter: can't enter into entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I don't understand why the entry boxes under `rackGUI.py` in my code are static/won't allow anything to be entered. I believe all the `Entry` objects are instantiated correctly. I specified the textvariable as instances of the `StringVar()`. My gut tells me the problem lies in command argument in `create_button` instantiation but I'm not really sure why. I thought by setting `command = lambda:function` the function would not be called.

Upon clicking `'New'` in the menu, `main.py` successfully calls `rackGUI.create()` which successfully calls `input_form()`. Clicking the button `'create_button'` successfully calls `drawRack` which prints to the shell `'test'`. I also added a test where I printed the type of value for each entry box i.e., `print type(rack_name.get())` and this successfully returns type `'str'`.

So again the main problem is that the entry box is static.

Below is my code:

config.py

```
"""
config.py
"""

import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as tkmb

#setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TLA Database Tool")
frame = tk.Frame(height = 300, width = 250)
frame.pack()
```

main.py

```
#main.py
from config import *
import rackGUI

def createRackTemplate():
    rackGUI.create()
def loadRackTemplate():
    rackGUI.load()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label = "New", command = createRackTemplate)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Load", command = loadRackTemplate)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)

tkmb.showinfo("Welcome", "Under File click New to create a new rack template.\n\
Click load to load rack template.")
root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

rackGUI.py

```
"""
rackGUI.py
"""
from config import *

def input_form():
    form_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
    form_frame.pack()

    tk.Label(form_frame, text = "Rack Template Name (e.g., Knox Type 4)").pack()
    rack_name = tk.Entry(form_frame, textvariable = tk.StringVar())
    rack_name.pack()
    tk.Label(form_frame, text = "Dimensions").pack()
    tk.Label(form_frame, text = "#rack rows").pack()
    num_rack_rows = tk.Entry(form_frame, textvariable = tk.StringVar())
    num_rack_rows.pack()
    tk.Label(form_frame, text = "#nodes per row").pack()
    num_slots = tk.Entry(form_frame, textvariable = tk.StringVar())
    num_slots.pack()

    create_button = tk.Button(form_frame, text = "Create!",\
              command = lambda: drawRack(rack_name, num_rack_rows, num_slots))
    create_button.pack()

def drawRack(rack_name, num_rack_rows, num_slots):
    print rack_name.get(), num_rack_rows.get(), num_slots.get()

def create():    
    input_form()

def load():
    pass
```

Comment: It works for me - Linux Mint 16, Python 2.7.5

Comment: What do you mean: `won't allow anything to be entered` ? You can't use keyboard or you can't set text in entry using `set("text")` ?

Comment: as in I try to click on the box but the text cursor won't show so I can't type anything in.

Comment: If you aren't saving a reference to your StringVars, they are completely unnecessary and can be removed. I doubt that's the source of the problem, however.

Comment: According to documentation on this site however (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm) it says that to retrieve the text I need to set the textvariable option to an instance of StringVar().

Comment: First time I see `textvariable = tk.StringVar()`. Use `myVar = tk.StringVar() ; tk.Entry( ... textvariable=myVar ...) ; old = myVar.get() ; myVar.set("new")`. Now `myVar` is an instance of `StringVar()` But it shouldn't be source of problem.

Comment: @user3761743: that tutorial is wrong. You can get the value without a textvariable.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: thank you for correction.

Comment: Maybe it's just my computer acting weird but I can now use my keyboard to input into the Entry objects but I first have to click outside the tkinter window to do so. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: @user3761743: are you running this on a Mac? Tkinter on OSX sometimes has focus issues.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who comes here after me, my solution ended up being

```py
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

Working fine on Windows, but causing this text entry problem on Mac.

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu as well. Removed this line and problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the problem there. The issue seems to be the focus of the windows, since you're using a messagebox.

In my script I just had put a `root.update()` before opening another window (in my case a filedialog) and everything worked fine. There's an already existing issue for that: https://bugs.python.org/issue42867#msg384785

Answer (score 0):

> tkinter: can't enter into entry widget

**For Python 2.7** and for **Python 3.x**, you can comment in or comment out.

You had too many windows' garbage. In other, to prevent window garbage. That why you are not calling `import tkinter`

We be focus on Python 3.x, as I do not have Python 2.7.

- Move `import rackGU`I inside `createRackTemplate()` function. This
  will prevent garbage window.

For main.py:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

from config import * #Python 3.x
#import tkMessageBox as tkmb Python 2.7
 

def createRackTemplate():
    import rackGUI
    rackGUI.create()
    
def loadRackTemplate():
    test_3.load()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label = "New", command = createRackTemplate)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Load", command = loadRackTemplate)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)

#Python 3.x
messagebox.showinfo("Welcome", "Under File click New to create a new rack template.\n\
Click load to load rack template.")


#Comment in for Python 2.7
#tkmb.showinfo("Welcome", "Under File click New to create a new rack template.\n\
#Click load to load rack template.")

root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

For config.py:

```
"""
config.py
"""

import tkinter as tk #Python 3.x
#import Tkinter as tk #Python 2.7

from tkinter import messagebox #Python 3.x
#import tkMessageBox as tkmb #Python 2.7

#setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TLA Database Tool")
frame = tk.Frame(height = 300, width = 250)
frame.pack()
```

For rackGUI.py:

- Add module `import tkinter as tk` and add frame = tk.Tk(). Because you are calling frame for every `tkinter` widgets

Code:

```
from config import *
import tkinter as tk


frame = tk.Tk()
...
...
```

Screenshot for Python 3.x:

[image]