# Tkinter Entry Widget with Overrideredirect and Fullscreen

Tags: python, user-interface, authentication, tkinter

I hope this is not a double post but I have not seen the answer to my question specifically throughout Google and the forums.

Basically for some reason, when I create an Entry widget; it will not allow for user input from the keyboard when I set my GUI to be fullscreen through self.attributes('-fullscreen', True) and when self.overrideredirect(True) is enabled as well. (I am going for a kiosk mode style GUI so a standard user cannot exit the interface)

I went through this link here ([tkinter: can't enter into entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24499711/8168134)) and found that their issue was similar but not exactly the same. I understand that there are some issues with this on Mac but there must be some other way to perform this task. This issue also occurred when I ran this on Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. When fullscreen is not active but override redirect is active, it works; and when override redirect is not active but fullscreen is active it also works.

I have tried set focus with focus_force() and focus_set() for the widget as well as the frame it is resting in however that did not work either.

My relavent code is provided below. If more of my code is needed, just let me know. The purpose of this piece of code is a username/password login method that will get called throughout the rest of my program.

I am running PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5. Thanks in advance!

CODE

```
    def admin(self, root_1):
        master = tk.Tk()
        text = ""

        master.title("Administrator Login")
        w_0, h_0 = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
        master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w_0, h_0))

        f1 = tk.Frame(master, width=w_0, height=h_0, background="red")
        f2 = tk.Frame(master, width=w_0, height=h_0, background="blue")

        f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

        master.wm_attributes('-topmost', 'True')
        master.overrideredirect(True)

        instruction_label = tk.Label(f2, text="Please type your username and password", fg="red", bg="blue",
                                     font=("Helvetica", 26))
        instruction_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20)
        user_label = tk.Label(f2, text="Username", font=("Helvetica", 16), bg="red")
        user_entry = tk.Entry(f2, bg="red")
        pass_label = tk.Label(f2, text="Password", font=("Helvetica", 16), bg="red")
        pass_entry = tk.Entry(f2, bg="red", show="*")

        user_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=("E", "W"), padx=20, pady=10)
        user_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=10)
        pass_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=("E", "W"), padx=20, pady=10)
        pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=10)

        user_entry.focus_force()

        submit_button = tk.Button(f2, text="Submit", command=lambda: correct_login(text), bg="red", width = 20, height = 4)
        submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=("N", "S", "E"), padx=20, pady=20)
        quit_button = tk.Button(f2, text="Quit", command=destroy, bg="red", width = 20, height = 4)
        quit_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=("N", "S", "W"), padx=20, pady=20)

        user_entry.delete(0)
        user_entry.insert(0, "")

        pass_entry.delete(0)
        pass_entry.insert(0, "")

        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a red flag in your code that should be fixed (it won't solve your problem, but it's free advice). You're passing in `root` to you admin method, and then you're calling Tk() **again** to create the toplevel that you're working with. This is not a good practice. Just use the command Toplevel. See my sample code below.

The posts you've seen are consistent (and correct apparently) for the MAC regarding overrideredirect. This attribute on a toplevel window tells the window manager to ignore some events on unparented windows. Apparently, the MAC does not send keypress and release events to widgets within an unparented toplevel window.

One workaround for this would be to allow the window to be parented (normal), but set the "WM_DELETE_WINDOW" protocol to a function or method to intercept window closure. I'm only posting the top portion of your admin method.

```
def admin(self, root_1):
    master = Toplevel()
    text = ""

    master.title("Administrator Login")
    w_0, h_0 = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
    master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w_0, h_0))
    master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.dontDeleteWindow)


def dontDeleteWindow(self):
    print("User tied to close window")
```

Comment: Ron, I appreciate the input and advice. The purpose that I had for passing in the root in my admin method is so that I could use root.withdraw() to allow me to not display the parent window in the background because I could see parts of the parent window behind the frames. I then use root.deiconify() to bring back the parent window upon pressing the "quit" button in f2. (I didn't post all the code showing that to keep it shorter). With that being said, I am not familiar with what you show above. What exactly is the master.protocol doing? I am newer to python so I apologize.

Comment: If you try it out, you'll see. The tk protocol is a means of allowing applications to save unsaved data, much like a word processor or spreadsheet program does when you press the window close button in the title bar. In this way, the application does not merely close the window, but allows the programmer to do some work before or instead of closing the window. In the example I posted, it just prints a message, but you'll notice the window is not destroyed, unless you expressly tell it to with a master.destroy() or a sys.exit().